# 0 rep change summarized as +1

Tags: bug, reputation, user-page

On [Alex's reputation list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex?tab=reputation):
[image: 1 is displayed as the day's summary for June 9th, but the details indicate "no net reputation changes for this day".]
What gives?

Comment: I don't see that. I don't see any entry for June 9 on his reputation list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post that he down voted was deleted, hence the 1 rep it cost him to cast the vote was refunded. It's a zero change because the refund simply gave him back rep he had already earned, he didn't earn any new rep by the down vote being refunded - *yet* +1 was added to the value that existed while the down vote was still in place.

You saw it the way you did because:

- You don't see what he voted on, only he does and
- You don't see deleted posts in other user's profiles

A little cryptic, but the only time you see a +1 where there's no rep cap at play, it means a down vote was refunded due to being rescinded, or the post being removed.

Comment: I'll accept this, I guess, as I trust it's the correct answer, but "There were no net reputation changes on this day" is a lie, and this should be fixed. It should instead give informative text without linking to the question.

Comment: @msh210 Well, I did edit that for clarification ;) There was a change, just no new rep. I'd agree that just saying 'downvote refunded' would be ideal, but it's quite a source of contention.

Comment: Why don't I see any entry for that day at all?

Comment: I'm seeing this now in a different user's profile, but only when I'm logged in (as a mod). When I open his profile in chrome incognito I don't see any entry. Why should that be? (The relevant entry is in a deleted comment to this post.)